# Octave is in an infinite loop?

Tags: octave

It seems like my Octave session is in an infinite loop or at least freezes up when I run this code

```
c = cos(pi/8)
s = sin(pi/8)
A = [c -s; s c]
xy = [1;0]
for i = 1:17
  xy = A * xy
  plot(xy(1), xy(2))
  hold on
endfor
```

When the code runs I am unable to close any of the windows and must force close the application.

Comment: It does work here. What are the output of `version`, `computer` and `graphics_toolkit` ?

Comment: is this on windoze and the first plot? This may take some minutes to build the fontconfig cache. Have you tried to wait at least 10min?

Comment: @ederag Version: 4.0.0  computer: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu graphics_toolkit: qt

Comment: @Andy I left it for about 20 minutes and still the same result

Comment: I checked with 4.0.0, also on linux; the plot is fast. Some checks should be done, like commenting out the plot command. Or the `xy` calculation/display (lots of outputs, the pager might be hanging). Then [search in the bug tracker](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=search&group=octave). And eventually [file a bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave).

Comment: A comma after the xy calculation solved the issue

Comment: @JohnHamlettIV Since this code actually works (at least for me) and not really an octave problem or any problem and even if it was a problem, you solved it...

Comment: @JohnHamlettIV: Since you output xy every loop, is it possible that your page blocks? Do you see "--less-- (f)orward..." at the bottom and after you press "q" you see the plot? If this is the case you have to disable the pager for example "more off" or add a ; after xy=A*xy;